# Issue in adding UIContainerveiw to SlideViewNavigation in StoryBoard iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uicontainerview

I am trying to add a persistent button at the bottom of view via UIContainerView in storyboard on SlidenavigationController.

But I am getting a blank view on navigation of left slide out(where as it is working fine with list of table contents on left slide out with out the container View) ([used a third party Tool with iOS-Slide-Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu) )

[image]

Storyboard

**Code for mainPageViewController**

```
      - (void)viewDidLoad {
          [super viewDidLoad];


          UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
          [[ParseServiceManager GetInstance] initializeParse];



         [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[LeftMenuViewController alloc] init]];;
        
      [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightMenu = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[RightMenuViewController alloc] init]];
         [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].menuRevealAnimationDuration = .18;
         [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].enableSwipeGesture = FALSE;

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidClose object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
    NSLog(@"Closed %@", menu);
}];

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidOpen object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
    NSLog(@"Opened %@", menu);
         }];

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidReveal object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
             NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
             NSLog(@"Revealed %@", menu);
         }];


     }
```

[image]

> Warning in Console as:
>
> SlideNavigationController has not been initialized. Either place one in your storyboard or initialize one in code

If any one have faced similar issue to initialise the Slide-navigation in CustomViewController instead of App delegate, please help me in solving this!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't add any UiNavigationController(SlidenavigationController) in Storyboard  Plz refer screenshot but initialized Programmatically like this below

### Push LoginView with SlideNavigationController from Appdelegate

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];

LoginViewController *loginView = (LoginViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LoginViewController"];
[loginView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
SlideNavigationController * slideNavCtl = [[SlideNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];
[self.window setRootViewController:slideNavCtl];
```

### Push HomeView with SlideNavigationController from Appdelegate

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
HomeViewController *homeView = (HomeViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
[homeView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
SlideNavigationController * slideNavCtl = [[SlideNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeView];
[self.window setRootViewController:slideNavCtl];

LeftMenuViewController *leftMenu2 = (LeftMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftMenuViewController"];
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = leftMenu2;
```

After LOGIN from LOGINVIEW I will push to HOMEVIEW view  with LeftMenuViewController or SideBarViewController like this

```
 if(Login){

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"     bundle: nil]; 
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"HomeViewController"];


-----This is Important ,You need assign ur LeftMenu or SidebarViewcontroller here-----------------

LeftMenuViewController *leftMenu2 = (LeftMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard                                                                     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftMenuViewController"];
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = leftMenu2;
 ------------------------------

[[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] pushViewController:vc animated:YES]; 

 }else {
nslog(@"Login Update failed")

}
```

[image]

Comment: You save me, Thank you.

Comment: Always Welcome @iOSBadBoy