# iOS slide-menu - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller, side-menu

In my project I have existing side menu i.e swrevealviewcontrtoller to display right side menu.It is working correctly. I want to add second right menu in between the project using slideNavigationController. This is the screen shot of my storyboard. I can not touch existing base code and Before login page I want to add slideNavigationController to display another right sidemenubar.
i.e not my root view controller for that I referred  these two links.[SlideNavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264600/issue-in-adding-uicontainerveiw-to-slideviewnavigation-in-storyboard-ios/37463424),[Solution for making rootviewcontroller](http://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu/issues/80)

[StoryBoard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKjQT.png)

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

 LoginViewController *loginView = (LoginViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Login"];
 [loginView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
 SlideNavigationController * slideNavCtl = [[SlideNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];
 [self.window setRootViewController:slideNavCtl];
```

It is taking LoginViewController as root view controller.

As we are using SwrevealViewController at the first it contains modal segue so I am not able to display the right menu in login view controller. After adding that code in app delegate I am able to display right menu in loginpage but login page is the rootview  but I want splash screen as a rootViewController. Using SlideNavigationController I want to display another right menu in login .

Comment: Hey could you check [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] API 
 LeftMenuViewController *leftMenu = [[LeftMenuViewController alloc] init];
        RightMenuViewController *rightMenu = [[RightMenuViewController alloc] init];
 
 [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightMenu = rightMenu;
 [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = leftMenu;

Comment: I didn't get you please tell me in breaf

Comment: [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightMenu = slideNavCtl;
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = slideNavCtl;  comment your last line //[self.window setRootViewController:slideNavCtl];

Comment: I added this code in app delegate its showing blank right menu  LoginNewViewController *homeView = (LoginNewViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewcontroller"];
        [homeView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        SlideNavigationController * slideNavCtl = [[SlideNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeView];
       // [self.window setRootViewController:slideNavCtl];
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightMenu = slideNavCtl;

Comment: Could you check the demo(SlideNavigationController from git ) how the have configured in slide menu in AppDelegate without setting root view controller.This should fix.